# Xamarin MvvmCross Fragment class cast exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm trying to figure out what to do for this class cast exception. I am following directly from Stuart's example and I seem to be stuck here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Android.Views.InflateException: Exception of type 'Android.Views.InflateException' was thrown.

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   md5d958475ca14cd4931af92c1266ed3aa8.DrawerFragment cannot be cast to
>   android.app.Fragment

DrawerFragment extends MvxFragment

```
var drawerFragment = (DrawerFragment)this.SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.drawer_fragment);
```

Fragment being added in .axml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/myDrawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- Main Content View-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <fragment
        class="Sample.Android.Views.DrawerFragment"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer Layout -->
    <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:id="@+id/leftListView"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#D2D2D2"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:background="#F2F2F2"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource DrawerItems"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/simple_list_item" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Your `DrawerFragment` class **does** extend Fragment, right?

Comment: DrawerFragment extends MvxFragment. Sorry should of mentioned the project is based on MvvmCross

Comment: I have revised the question. I believe it to be an inflation issue and I have posted the entire xml layout.

Comment: can you post your setup.cs

Comment: I would look into https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples

It is much more updated to the latest MvvmCross and Android support libraries.